# "A solo n anni" oppure "a soli n anni"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Qual è la forma corretta, "a solo *n* anni" oppure "a soli *n* anni"? (dove *n* è un numero naturale). Ad esempio, quale tra queste due frasi sarebbe la forma giusta?

> - Si è laureata *a solo 20 anni*.
> - Si è laureata *a soli 20 anni*.

Comment: Un'altra possibilità è «...ad appena 20 anni», ma nella vita vera riformulerei in qualcosa come «Aveva solo/appena 20 anni quando si è laureata».

Comment: Curiosamente, se si fosse laureata a 30 (cioè tardi e non presto) diremmo: "si è laureata solo a 30 anni" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corretto è "a soli 20 anni", perché "soli" qui è aggettivo.

Puoi anche usare l'avverbio, ma suona agrammaticale se lo metti in mezzo al sintagma "a 20 anni". Puoi dire "solo a 20 anni" (ma il significato è diverso), o "a 20 anni soltanto", "a 20 anni solamente", "a 20 anni solo" (tre opzioni in ordine decrescente di accettabilità; solo la prima normalmente considerabile corretta, direi).

Comment: Ho trovato molti esempi di questo costrutto in Google Books:
https://www.google.es/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=GGIC+italiano&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=96PDVMa9BYyt8wfP-4DIBw&gws_rd=ssl#channel=fs&tbm=bks&q=%22a+soli+vent%27anni%22

Comment: Ci sono alcuni [esempi di uso di "a solo vent'anni"](https://books.google.es/books?id=2jCNYMnOdXUC&pg=PA183&dq=%22a+solo+vent%27anni%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dabDVMT-H8OwUYicgMgH&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22a%20solo%20vent%27anni%22&f=false) che penso abbiano un senso diverso: «Eppure il rinnovato amore per queste ricerche ha già dato i suoi frutti, e noi oggi, *a solo vent'anni* dallo studio del Verzone, possiamo già avvalerci di diversi nuovi elementi, non forse validi per risolvere problemi d'ordine artistico, quali in sostanza si proponeva appunto il Verzone, ma di storia positiva;».

Comment: Quell'esempio è diverso, perché è "a vent'anni da". Quindi è diversa l'interruzione causata dal mettere in mezzo un avverbio. Il risultato però è lo stesso: un intervallo temporale di 20 anni è indicato come piccolo.

Comment: E immagino lo stesso ragionamento sia valido per vedere che si debba usare "soli" e non "solo" in altre espressioni simili, come, per esempio, in questa frase dal racconto *Nichel*, dal *Sistema periodico* di Primo Levi: "La pianura era a soli cinque chilometri, ma la miniera era a tutti gli effetti una piccola repubblica autonoma".

Answer (score 1):

Mi pare  corretto e  di uso abbastanza comune avere una preposizione che introduce un complemento modificato da un avverbio. "Di circa un metro", "A solo vent'anni", "Da neppure tanto", "In troppo pochi", "Con quasi tutti"…

(*edit*)  Mi pare che nelle altre lingue, inclusi il latino e il greco, e forse anche in un italiano meno recente, nella frase della domanda si userebbe senz'altro l'avverbio, e ciò abbastanza indipendentemente dalla sua posizione o dalla presenza di una preposizione. Di certo: (1) "*sono venute solo tre persone*" = "c'era poca gente"; (2) "*sono venute tre persone sole*" = "non accompagnate", o anche, "ognuno per conto suo". Mi pare invece che  (3) "*sono venute tre sole persone*" vorrebbe avere il significato della forma (1), ma l'esistenza di un aggettivo "solo" induce a usarlo e  a fare la concordanza, con correttezza un po' dubbia (lessicale, non grammaticale).

Comment: Qualcuno ha una GGIC a portata di mano? :) Anche a me alcuni dei tuoi esempi sembrano accettabili, ma ce ne servono di migliori: nessuno di essi è, come "solo 20 anni", un aggettivo che serva anche da avverbio + un sostantivo. Visto che Charo è straniera, ho preferito cogliere l'opportunità di sottolineare la distinzione fra avverbio e aggettivo, che mi sembra di utilità abbastanza frequente.

Comment: In effetti in quegli esempi solo "troppo" è un altro  aggettivo & avverbio. La mia impressione (guardando il numero di risultati di google) è che "a soli venti" sia una forma più comune oggi. "A solo venti" forse è una forma più classica.